# PyQt application and infinite loop

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    gui = GUIClass()
    gui.showUI()

    app.exec_()

    while True:
        if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_SHIFT):
            print(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code after app.exec_() doesn't running. How to do infinite loop and run my PyQt application?

Thanks.

Comment: app.exec() is a blocking call. Only after you exit the gui will it unblock and code after it will start running.

Comment: @Pratham, Oh! I can't make infinite loop with running application?

Comment: Answer given by "mdurant" is what you should do. I couldn't understand what you meant by "infinite loop with running application" ..

Comment: @Pratham, I just create thread and put loop (while) to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pyqt comes with its own (infinite) event loop so that you don't have to build your own. `app.exec_()` enters this loop, which is why you don't see the code following that execute. Only after you have closed all qt windows will anything remaining be executed.

Example of QTimer usage:

in `main()` before `exec_()`:

```
def timout():
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_SHIFT):
        print(True)

timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
timer.timeout.connect(timeout)
timer.start(100)
```

Comment: Huh. I can't make infinite loop with running application?

Comment: You CAN have other things running while the main application runs, but typically these are responses to events via the slot mechanism; you could use a QTimer to repeatedly run arbitrary code while the GUI is live. If none of this makes sense, then you should go to the pyqt4 tutorials/examples.