# Use QTimer to run functions in an infinte loop

Tags: python, loops, pyqt5, qtimer

I'm new to Python and still trying to learn, but I couldn't handle this problem. I want to run some functions (which are in class) in an infinite loop. Because it is a QApplication, I've learned that I should do it with a QTimer. However, when exploring how to do it, I couldn't find a working alternative. A common solution is:

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(function)
timer.start(60000)
```

But when I insert these into my code it makes no difference. I have tried to insert it under functions, class, etc, but couldn't get a result. My functions to loop are here:

```
__author__ = 'pc'
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import sqlite3
import sys, getopt, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

records = []
def scrape_page(url, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find('div', class_='tablo_dual_board')
    try:
        datas = data.text.splitlines()
        datas1 = list(filter(None, datas))
        records.append(datas1)
    except:
        pass

def process_records():
    # add record to database ...
    print('process records:', len(records))

def generate_urls():
    onexurl = "https://1xbahis19.com/en/live/Football/"
    reply = requests.get(onexurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reply.content, "html.parser")
    income = soup.find_all("ul", {"id":"games_content"})
    links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "c-events__name"})
    urls = []
    for matchlink in links:
        urls.append("https://1xbahis19.com/en/"+(matchlink.get("href")))
    return urls

class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)

    def start(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        return True

    def processCurrentPage(self, html):
        scrape_page(self.url().toString(), html)
        if not self.fetchNext():
            process_records()
            print(records)
            QtWidgets.qApp.quit()

    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self.toHtml(self.processCurrentPage)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
webpage = WebPage()
webpage.start(generate_urls())
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(WebPage)
timer.start(60000)
app.exec_()
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: Where did you get or who told you to use a timer?

Comment: @eyllanesc I've learned from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080561/pyqt-application-and-infinite-loop) and othe stacoverflow posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to run the scraper at regular intervals. The script below will scrape all the urls once every 60 seconds. The `signal` part is there to provide a way to terminate the infinite loop - just do <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (i.e. `KeyboardInterrupt`), and it will stop immediately.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import sqlite3
import sys, getopt, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

import signal
# press Ctrl+C to stop the script
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

records = []
def scrape_page(url, html):
    print('scraping page:', url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find('div', class_='tablo_dual_board')
    try:
        datas = data.text.splitlines()
        datas1 = list(filter(None, datas))
        records.append(datas1)
    except:
        pass

def process_records():
    # add record to database ...
    print('processed records:', len(records))
    # clear the current records
    del records[:]
    # re-run after a timeout
    QTimer.singleShot(60000, run)

def run():
    print('running scraper...')
    webpage.start(generate_urls())

def generate_urls():
    print('generating urls...')
    onexurl = "https://1xbahis19.com/en/live/Football/"
    reply = requests.get(onexurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reply.content, "html.parser")
    income = soup.find_all("ul", {"id":"games_content"})
    links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "c-events__name"})
    urls = []
    for matchlink in links:
        urls.append("https://1xbahis19.com/en/"+(matchlink.get("href")))
    return urls

class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)

    def start(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        return True

    def processCurrentPage(self, html):
        scrape_page(self.url().toString(), html)
        if not self.fetchNext():
            process_records()

    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self.toHtml(self.processCurrentPage)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
webpage = WebPage()
run()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you again ekhumoro, but I'm afraid I couldn't make it worked. It works perfect once, but doesn't loop. By the way as I know `timer.start(60000)` means 60 seconds not 60 minutes, right? Additionally, I have copied and added your codes directly, so I think it's calling `run()` separately.

Comment: @AhmetUluer. See my updated answer. I think the main problem with your script was that you needed to remove the line in `processCurrentPage` that was quitting the application after the current batch of urls was processed.

Comment: Again and again thank you very much, you saved my days. It works perfectly.